# Nice problem of combinatorics..

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I know a family that has $10$ children and half of them are married.
Sometimes they ask me about mathematics, and ask me to show them nice things...
I asked them: ***How many possible ways there are to pick $5$ of your children and that $3$ of them (at our selection) will be married?***
I explain them that this is a problem at combinatorics.

My answer (and I'll be glad if you will correct me): $$\binom{5}{3}\cdot \binom{5}{2}$$  Why?
First of all we choosing $3$ married children from the $5$ that we have - and this is $\binom{5}{3}$.
Than, we have another more $5$ children to choose $2$ from them, and this is why we have   $\binom{5}{2}$.

If the **question** was that we can have more then $3$ married children so the answer will be:$$\binom{5}{3}\cdot \binom{7}{2}$$ Why?
Because we move the unchosen married children to the group of the unmarried children...

At the next section I asked the same thing but I added one more thing - that the minimum of married children can be $1$ and the maximum is $4$ (e.g. at $2$ there can only be $2$ married children and no more... IF there can be more it will $7$ at the right binom and 5), my answer is: $$\sum_{i=1}^{4}\binom{5}{i}\cdot \binom{5}{5-i}$$ I'm right?

I just want to tell you that I didn't show my answers to the family, I put here to know if I'm right...

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first and the third are right, but the second is not right.

For the second, let $A,B,C,D,E$ are married children and let $F,G,H,I,J$ are unmarried children.

Then, $\binom{5}{3}\cdot \binom{7}{2}(=210)$ counts a set $\{ABCDE\}$ multiple times.

1) First you choose $A,B,C$ and you choose $D,E$.

2) First you choose $A,C,D$ and you choose $B,E$.

and so on...

So, the answer is 
$$\binom{5}{3}\binom{5}{2}+\binom{5}{4}\binom{5}{1}+\binom{5}{5}\binom{5}{0}=100+25+1=126$$
in the same way as the first and the third.

Comment: Thank you! You are talking about this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle (At the second one).

Comment: And why I count $\left\{ABCDE\right\}$ multiple times? Because the second the to married children moves to the other group.... Thank you!

Comment: Well, not really. Also, I've already explained it. Do you see the points 1) 2) I wrote?

Comment: @YoavFridman: 1) means that first you choose $ABC$ from married children and $DE$ from the left (as you said, the number of the left is seven. So, we can choose $DE$, right?). 2) means the same. So, a set $\{ABCDE\}$ is counted at least twice.

Comment: Oh, I see, you explain why I'm wrong, right?

Comment: Yes. You are right in the first and the third. So, you can use the idea for the first and the third to the second too. That's what I want to say.

Comment: So, why at the second is $\binom{5}{3}\binom{5}{2}+\binom{5}{4}\binom{5}{1}+\binom{5}{5}\binom{5}{0}$? I don't understand... Why it's three times and not two...

Comment: Why? Because the number of married children is either $3,4$ or $5$. You did the same argument in the third. Or your 'more than 3' does not include $3$? If so, the answer is $\binom{5}{4}\binom{4}{1}+\binom{5}{5}\binom{5}{0}$.

Comment: If I'm understanding right, so because we always pick just one from this group and one from the other group, right?

Comment: But at the second one I meant that can be **more** then 3 married children e.g.: All of the 5 can be married...

Comment: But them you will have maximum of 3 married children...

Comment: I know it. So I added $\binom{5}{5}\binom{5}{0}$, which is equal to $1$.

Comment: You mean the number of married children is either $3,4,$ or $5$, right? So, consider each case separately.

Comment: Yes, I understanding it now! The first one is if we have 3 married children at our selection, the second is 4 and so one... right?

Comment: Yes. $\binom{5}{3}\binom{5}{2}$ represents the case in which the number of married children is $3$. $\binom{5}{4}\binom{5}{1}$ represents the case in which the number of married children is $4$. $\binom{5}{5}\binom{5}{0}$ represents the case in which the number of married children is $5$.

Comment: Yes, this what I wrote at my answer :-)

Comment: mathlove, can you explain me one more thing? Why we use the $+$ sign?

Comment: @YoavFridman: Because we want to know the combination of the case in which the number of married children is $3$ and the combination of the case in which the number of married children is $4$ and the combination of the case in which the number of married children is $5$.

Comment: I meant 'or', not 'and'.