# Continued: Nice Problem of Combinatorics.....

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Here is the previous Q: [Nice problem of combinatorics..](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/642796/nice-problem-of-combinatorics)
Now the question is this:
(4 of the children are girls.)
***How many ways there is to pick-up 5 children from the 10, that 3 of them will be married and 2 of them will be girls??***
And the second part is: that must be *at least* 2 girls...

I'd like to get help with this...
I should use this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle or something else?

Thank you!

Comment: Please that the entire question so that it is self-contained. Also, you problem is missing information, namely how many of the girls are married. Since your other question states half (so $5$) of the children are maried, choosing $5$ so that they are all married can be done in only one way; whether that choice involves two girls cannot be said.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen, sorry you right, I fix my mistake...
Why it's matter if the girls are married or not? Thank you!

Comment: It has nothing at all to do with group theory, so that tag is misplaced.

Comment: @DerekHolt, I didn't know, thank you!

Comment: @Newb - 4.... why?

Comment: @YoavFridman your question is currently unanswerable because we don't know how many of the married children are girls. E.g. if all $5$ married children are girls, the situation is much different from if $2$ of the married children are girls.